# Matrix norm differentiation problem.

Tags: matrices, solution-verification, matrix-calculus

Consider $J = \|X - AS\|^2$, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times R}$, $S \in \mathbb{R}^{R \times M}$.

We need to calculate $\dfrac{d J}{d S}$.

I've done the following:

$J = \operatorname{tr}((X - AS)(X - AS)^\top) = \operatorname{tr}((X-AS) (X^\top - S^\top A^\top)) = \operatorname{tr}(XX^\top - ASX^\top - XS^\top A^\top + ASS^\top A^\top)$ and hence

$$\dfrac{dJ}{dS} = \dfrac{-\operatorname{tr}(ASX) - \operatorname{tr}(XS^\top A^\top) + \operatorname{tr}(ASS^\top A^\top)}{dS}$$

1. $\dfrac{d\operatorname{tr}(ASX)}{dS} = \dfrac{d\operatorname{tr}(SXA)}{dS} = (XA)^\top = A^\top X^\top$
2. $\dfrac{d\operatorname{tr}(XS^\top A^\top)}{dS} = \dfrac{d\operatorname{tr}((XS^\top A^\top)^\top}{dS} = \dfrac{d\operatorname{tr}(ASX^\top)}{dS} = \dfrac{\operatorname{tr}(SX^\top A)}{dS} = (X^\top A)^\top = A^\top X$
3. $\dfrac{d\operatorname{tr}(AS(AS)^\top)}{dS}$, so $$\displaystyle \dfrac{d\sum_{n,m}(AS)_{n,m} ((AS)^\top)_{m,n}}{d s_{i,j}} = \dfrac{d\sum_{n,m}(AS)^2_{n,m}}{d s_{i,j}} = \dfrac{d \sum_{n,m} \left(\sum_{q} a_{n,q} s_{q,m}\right)^2}{d s_{i,j}} = \dfrac{d\sum_{n,m} \sum_{q}a_{n,q}s_{q,m} \sum_{l}a_{n,l} s_{l,m}}{ds_{i,j}} =$$ $$\sum_{n,m} \sum_{q} \sum_{l} a_{n,q} s_{q,m} a_{n,l} \delta_{l}^{i} \delta_{m}^{j} = \sum_{n} \sum_{q} a_{n,q}s_{q,j} a_{n, i} = \sum_{n} A^\top_{i,n}(AS)_{n,j} = (A^\top A S)_{i,j}$$

Hence we have: $\dfrac{dJ}{dS} = A^\top (AS - X - X^\top)$. Unfortunately, I'm very bad at matrix calculus and do not use some kind of properties. I'm interested in whether my approach is OK?

Comment: why did you start using the sum notation in the last step? Makes it very diffult to read in my opinion. The property $\mathrm{trace}((X-AS)'(X-AS)) = \mathrm{vec}(X - AS)'\mathrm{vec}(X - AS)$ may simplify alot of your calculations since the operator is linear so $\mathrm{vec}(X - AS) = \mathrm{vec}(X) - \mathrm{vec}(AS)$ and $\mathrm{vec}(AS) = (I_M\otimes A)\mathrm{vec}(S)$. This allows you taking the derivative of a scalar function wrt to the vector $\mathrm{vec}(S)$

Comment: \begin{align*} \frac{dJ}{dS}\dot{S} &= \left.\frac{d}{dt}J(S+t\dot{S})\right|_{t=0}\\ &= \left.\frac{d}{dt}\mathrm{tr} (X - AS- tA\dot{S})^T(X-AS-tA\dot{S})\right|_{t=0} \\ &= \mathrm{tr} (-A\dot{S})^T(X-AS) - (X-AS)^T(A\dot{S}) \end{align*}

Comment: Why not calculate $\frac{dJ}{dS}(v)$ for any valid argument $v$?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I understand that it's possible to derive using other ideas. I'm interesting if my answer is correct and my calculations are valid

Comment: @Deane I understand that there is another approach. But I'm interested in native proof

Comment: A "native proof" would be one that doesn't need coordinates.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe okay. I understand. At least I'm interested in if the answer is correct.

Comment: If all you want to know is if your answer is correct or not, then I can verify that it is **not**.

Comment: @greg thanks for the answer. But I always thought that "solution-verification" means comments according to given solution. Not probable one.

Comment: The solution is wrong and the solution method is _needlessly_ complicated, yet each time a commenter suggests a different (better) approach you promptly dismiss their advice. So it's unclear what kind of comment/answer you're hoping for. Maybe it's the following$:\quad$ The expression $(X\pm X^T)$ is dimensionally impossible for a rectangular $(M\times N)$ matrix. So identify the step where this expression first occurs in your calculation and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

We have, using $\operatorname{tr}(C+C^T)=2\operatorname{tr}(C)$
$$\begin{align}
d_SJ(v)&=\operatorname{tr}\bigl((-Av)^T(X-AS)+(X-AS)^T(-Av)\bigr)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\bigl((X-AS)^T(-Av)+((X-AS)^T(-Av))^T \bigr)\\
&=-2\operatorname{tr}\bigl((X-AS)^TAv\bigr)\\
&=-2\operatorname{tr}\bigl(\bigl(A^T(X-AS)\bigr)^Tv\bigr)\\
&=-2\langle (A^T(X-AS)),v\rangle.
\end{align}
$$
Hence $$d_SJ=-2(A^T(X-AS)).$$

EDIT (even simpler) Using chain and product rule:
$$d_SJ(v)=2\langle X-SA,-vA\rangle=-2\langle (A^T(X-AS)),v\rangle.$$